# return first column number that fulfills a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with several columns of cumulative sums. For every row, I want to return the first column number that satisfies a condition.

Toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(20)).reshape(4,5).T).cumsum(axis=1)

>>> df
   0   1   2   3
0  0   5  15  30
1  1   7  18  34
2  2   9  21  38
3  3  11  24  42
4  4  13  27  46
```

If I want to return the first column whose value is greater than 20 for instance.

Desired output:

```
3
3
2
2
2
```

Many thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `idxmax`

```
df.gt(20).idxmax(1)
Out[66]: 
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the numerical column number instead of the column name?

Comment: @user12346170 `df.columns.get_indexer(df.gt(20).idxmax(1))

`

Answer (score 1):

No as short as @YOBEN_S but works is the chaining of [index.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and [first_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html)

```
df[df>20].apply(lambda x: x.index.get_loc(x.first_valid_index()), axis=1)
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    2
dtype: int64
```